# Graphic card beeps on startup

Tags: boot, graphics-card, motherboard, bios

I know 'Graphic card beeping on startup' is a very common problem, but my problem is a little different. I have been using this graphic card for the past few months and it had been working fine. My graphic card is NVIDIA GT 630. My motherboard is Intel DH61WW. I installed the card on my own a few months ago. Yesterday, when I changed a few settings in 'Adjust the appearance and performance of windows' my pc restarted. And then I heard a beep from my pc. So in BIOS settings, I changed the default graphic card from 'Auto' to 'Internal Graphics', the pc booted up and then using device manager I changed it back to my graphic card. The problem is that whenever I try to start my computer with the 'Auto' option, I hear a beep! I always have to start with default graphics and then change back to graphic card. Can anyone help me?

Comment: I guess internal means, it should use the CPU integrated GPU. Can you set to "PCI"?

Comment: By internal i mean the motherboard's integrated GPU. Yes, I can choose PCI, but when I do, the same thing happens as in 'Auto' mode, it beeps and restarts, because auto mode automatically selects my graphic card in PCI slot.